# Jenkins: Prioritizing Matrix Jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a matrix job that run only on a certain virtual slave. It has two axis with two elements each. The job runs nightly, and each configuration takes 2-3 hours. Sometimes the results are needed the first things in the morning - and the configuration that is needed is still building.

Is it possible to build matrix jobs in certain order? I'd prefer a solution that is easily re-configurable.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin), although it's still buggy and requires a lot of work: [JENKINS-8597](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8597)

Comment: It does not give me an option to prioritize per configuration - only per parent job. Or am I missing something?

Comment: See [this commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/95c5ea279a4c1e60ff1596bb66c28b1902f84359). It should be deployed within next 2-3 releases.

Comment: From what I was able to understand he is making Matrix jobs into 'first class builds', which should probably fix a whole lot of problems. Let's see how it plays out. Thanks.

Comment: As I wrote - it's tricky, requires a lot of work and it's still buggy. But that's the only way for now. New API extension was made not a long ago, so there should be a new plugin or a new version of existing one to support it and, possibly, make the process less painful. Good luck!